# Laravel restore trashed not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

The restore function looks like it is working up until it saves its state in the Database. I have this code:

```
if($result->trashed()) {
     Log::info($result->deleted_at);

     $result->restore();

     Log::info($result->deleted_at);
}

$result->award_id = 1;
$result->save();

Log::info($result->deleted_at);
```

The debugs show the code working how it should like so:

```
2015-09-22
null
null
```

However, the record in the database is still showing a date in the deleted_at column.

I'm on Laravel 4.2.

Comment: check if the `deleted_at` column has a `NOT NULL` flag in your database table

Comment: The deleted_at column allows NULL

Comment: you can try logging the restore and save operations, see if any returns false

Comment: I have logged $result->restore() and it outputs 1 which means it executed fine. I will now try logging save().

Comment: I think I have found the reason as to why it's not working, here is the SQL the restore method is trying to execute:

`update UserClasses set updated_by = ?, deleted_at = ? where UserClasses.deleted_at is null and id = ?`

 `{"bindings":["1",null,"2086"],"time":0.72} []`

The WHERE statement is preventing the record from being found to do the restore. Is this an issue with Laravel or do I not have my Model configured correctly? It's using the SoftDelete Trait.

Comment: i assume you used `deleted_at` in your initial query then

Comment: To get my initial `$result` object, I added withTrashed() hence why my trashed() method returns true.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this is a pretty major bug with Laravel 4.2 as per the issue raised by myself on Github:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/10630#issuecomment-148739682

Unfortunately, 4.2 is no longer supported so I had to replace the restore() method with:

```
UserClass::where('user_id', '=', $user->id)
                ->where('class_id', '=', $class_id)
                ->withTrashed()
                ->update([
                      'deleted_at' => null
                ]);
```

As far as I know, this is still an issue with later versions of Laravel.